# I am coding a command that once ran would allow me to check the servers a user is in, however I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const {
  InteractionType,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  EmbedBuilder,
} = require("discord.js");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { token, clientId, guildId } = require("../../config.json");

const client = new Client({
  intents: Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits).map((a) => {
    return GatewayIntentBits[a];
  }),
});

const commandData = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("checkuserguilds")
  .setDescription("Check the guilds a user is in")
  .addUserOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("user")
      .setDescription("The user to check the guilds for")
      .setRequired(true)
  );

const allowedRoleName = "DOW Directors"; // Replace 'YOUR_ALLOWED_ROLE_NAME' with the name of the role allowed to run the command

client.once("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  const rest = new REST({ version: "9" }).setToken(token);

  try {
    console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
      body: [commandData.toJSON()],
    });

    console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

const execute = async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ApplicationCommand) {
    if (interaction.commandName === "checkuserguilds") {
      if (!checkPermission(interaction.member)) {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "You do not have permission to run this command.",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }

      const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
      if (!user) {
        return interaction.reply({
          content: "Please specify a user.",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }

      try {
        const guilds = await getUserGuilds(user.id);
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor("#0099ff")
          .setTitle("User Guilds")
          .setDescription(
            `User ${user.tag} is in the following guilds:\n${guilds.join("\n")}`
          );
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user guilds:", error);
        await interaction.reply("Error fetching user guilds.");
      }
    }
  }
};

function checkPermission(member) {
  return member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === allowedRoleName);
}

async function getUserGuilds(userId) {
  try {
    const user = await client.users.fetch(userId);
    const userGuilds = client.guilds.cache.filter((guild) =>
      guild.members.cache.has(user.id)
    );
    return userGuilds.map((guild) => guild.name);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching user guilds:", error);
    return [];
  }
}

module.exports = {
  data: commandData,
  execute,
};
```

I have tried to reset my tokens, and I am still receiving the "Error fetching user guilds: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present." I have configured the code to where I am not just handing out the token in all the commands. so it is centrally located in the config.json file.